# SoapUI: Customize assertion log text when assertion passes or fails

Tags: xml, groovy, soapui, assertions

I have a Script Assertion that compares value A from the XML response to value B, C, and D. If Value A is equal to any of value B, C, or D then the assertion passes, else it fails.

```
// get the xml response                                             
def response = messageExchange.getResponseContent()                                                 
// parse it                                             
def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(response)                                              
// find your node by name                                               
def node = xml.'**'.find { it.name() == 'total-premium' }                                               
// assert                                               
(assert node.toString().matches("(36.476|38.395|40.315)\\d*"))
```

At the moment for a passed assertion I get this string in the log:

```
Step 1 [TestStep_0001] OK: took 2296 ms
```

And a failed assertion I get this string in the log:

```
 -> [Script Assertion] assert node.toString().matches((36.476|38.395|40.315)\\d*")           |    |          |           |    37.6033658 false           37.6033658
```

As you can see it is a bit messy and I'm trying neaten up the test suite logs.

Is there a way to set customized response in the logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that this is what you're looking for, but you can customize your `assert` passing a string as a message which will be displayed or logged when `assert` fails.

Something like:

```
assert node.toString().matches("(36.476|38.395|40.315)\\d*"), 'Assert fail custom message'
```

This way when you execute the TestCase if the `assert` fail in the log you will see this instead:

```
[Script Assertion] Assert fail custom message. Expression: node.toString().matches((36.476|38.395|40.315)\d*)
```

**UPDATE BASED ON COMMENT:**

You don't have a method to remove a part of the `assert` message, if as shown in the previous solution the custom message using `assert expression, 'custom fail message'` it's not enough for your case (since seems that you also want to remove `Expression:` part in the result message); a possible solution to customize totally your message is to catch the `java.lang.AssertionError` exception thrown by the `assert` and print in the log the desired message:

```
def node = 3
try {
    assert node.toString().matches("(36.476|38.395|40.315)\\d*")
} catch (AssertionError e) {
    log.info "Your custom message without expression"
}
```

Comment: is there anyway to hide the Expression part?